# Convert UTC time to PST for Daylight savings time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, dst, nstimezone

My application gets some time slots from backend and convert that into current time zone (PST) and display. Everything is working perfect until Day light time savings is kicking in.

Is there a way in iOS to say like give me the PST date and time for this UTC and it will take care of Daylight savings day automatically. Currently its converting it fine but still giving me an hour off.

Here's what i am doing:

```
-(NSDate *) toLocalTime:(NSDate*) currentDate
{
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Pacific"];
    NSInteger seconds = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate: currentDate];
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: seconds sinceDate: currentDate];
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed my code to this but still the same result:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

    NSString *startDateString = [[self.slotsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"StartDate"];
    NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDateString];

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"]];

    NSString * dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startDate];
```

For example i am displaying some time slots for Mar 13 when the day light time kicks in. In UTC i am getting a time of 17:00 which is equivalent to 10 for us today. But the real time in this case will be 9 AM for that day. How should i fix that ?

Comment: Basically do **all** calendar calculations with `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` rather than using literal numbers like 86400

Comment: What do you mean by “the real time in this case will be 9 AM for that day”? If you don't want to do a straightforward time zone conversion (which produces 10 AM), describe how you want to convert the time.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what that method is supposed to be doing, but `NSDate` does not have any time zone information, so if you're "adjusting" one from one time zone to another, you're doing it wrong. The documentation for `NSDate` even says

> NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, **independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone.**

If you have an `NSDate` and you want to present it to the user in the local time for a given time zone, you would do something like:

```
NSDate *date = // from somewhere

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"];

NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

This will give you a string with the correct date in the given time zone, for any `NSDate` you throw at it. Don't try to convert the `NSDate`.

**Extra** based on a comment:

Daylight saving time in the USA in 2016 begins on 13 March at 02:00. The time is moved **forward** by one hour at that moment. If you run the above code with a start date string of `@"03/12/2016 17:00:00"` (before the time change) the final result is `Mar 12, 2016, 9:00:00 AM`. If you run it with a start date string of `@"03/13/2016 17:00:00"` (after the time change), the result is `Mar 13, 2016, 10:00:00 AM`.

As a result, the code correctly adjusts for daylight saving time by returning a different time before and after DST starts, and by correctly returning a later time of day during DST. You seem to be getting the same result, so I'm no longer sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: See my edit above. I think by either of these ways i am getting the correct date as per today. But 10 AM today will be 9AM on that day. But if i look at that today it shows me 10 instead of 9. The UTC i am getting is 17:00:00

Comment: Can you give an example of the date strings you're starting with that lead to incorrect results?

Comment: This is value i am getting in startDateString "03/13/2016 17:00:00" and then my dateString comes out as "Mar 13, 2016, 10:00:00 AM" which is correct but on that day it would be 9:00 AM.

Comment: No. Daylight saving time in the North American Pacific Time Zone begins at 2016-03-13 10:00:00 UTC, which is before 2016-03-13 17:00:00 UTC. Therefore the Pacific time zone offset at 2016-03-13 17:00:00 UTC is -7 hours. 17 - 7 = 10, so 2016-03-13 17:00:00 UTC is 2016-03-13 10:00:00 in the Pacific time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `US/Pacific` try replacing it with `America/Los_Angeles`, it will automatically detect **DST** and change the time zone to **-7**.

I  work on some applications getting a time in UTC from the server and we've never had a problem using this.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:
Given date in formate "2018-03-13 07:00:00 +0000" returned value should be ""2018-03-12"

```
func PDTForamte(endTime: String) -> String{
    // create dateFormatter with UTC time format
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+zzzz"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: endTime) else {
        return endTime.components(separatedBy: "T").first ?? "" //return date before 'T'.
    }

    let pdtFormatter = DateFormatter()
    pdtFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    pdtFormatter.timeStyle = .long
    if let americaZone = NSTimeZone(name: "America/Los_Angeles") {
        pdtFormatter.timeZone = americaZone as TimeZone
    }

    let dateString: String = pdtFormatter.string(from: date)

    let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrent
    //We subtract 1 min because American Date here be 12:00:00 AM but It should be return to the previous day
    let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -1, to: pdtFormatter.date(from: dateString)!) ?? Date()
    pdtFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let newDateString: String = pdtFormatter.string(from: newDate)

    return newDateString
}
```